# what is advantage of binderised hidl comparing to passthrough?

Tags: android, android-source, hal

In android, what's advantage of binderised hidl comparing to passthrough hidl?

As i know, there are two hidl way (binderised way(client/server in seperated process) , passthrough way (client /server in same process).
What is advantage of binderised way comparing to passthrough way?

I think binderised way has more overhead than passthrough because binderised way need to use binder communication(RPC).

Why does vendor use binderised way?

Answer (score 5):

**binderized** means that your service is provided via `/dev/hwbinder` and hosted in a separate process. This allows it to have exclusive access to a hardware resource and still offer the service to multiple clients at once.

**passthrough** means that your service is provided via a C++ interface in a shared library. This usually implies that only one client can link to it or the service must be implemented in a way that it does not need exclusive access to hardware. The upside is that you save the communication overhead of using Binder.

You would typically use binderized HALs as the the Binder RPC overhead is really small (smaller than with framework Binder and `AIDL`).

There is a list of HALs that [need to be implemented in passthrough](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hal-types#passthrough) mode (for performance reasons), and a list of HALs that [need to be implemented in binderized](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hal-types#binderized) mode.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually more to it than the above answer, which is somewhat inaccurate. "Binderized" indeed means that the service is hosted by a server, accessible over hwbinder, but it has little to do with exclusivity (which passthrough hals do NOT imply, and in fact multiple clients can link with them - the exclusivity is solely at the discretion of the kernel driver).

As part of Project Treble (Android 8.0 refactoring and moving into /vendor, /product, /odm), Google brought in the notion of a Binderized HAL to make sure no vendor HAL code intermixes with AOSP code. Numerous times before this, vulnerable vendor code executed in the context of system_server, and he owns system_server owns Android (i.e. complete and utter system compromise).

Using binderized HALs incurs the same nasty overhead (actually about the same as framework binder and AIDL), but allows complete separation of vendor code. Vendor code can no longer access AOSP services - that is, vendor daemons can open /dev/vndbinder , but not /dev/binder - which means that even if they are compromised there is more chance of containment, preventing malicious code from attacking AOSP services.

Passthrough HALs are definitely better and far more performant - but explicitly deprecated by Google (with the exception of android.hardware.graphics.mapper and maybe one or two more which elude me at the moment). They were allowed in 8.0 as part of the transition period , so as not to "shock" vendors too much. At this point (11.0, 12b3), they are not allowed on Android (per CTS, though vendors can still flout this)

Comment: Hi @Technologeeks. Thank you for the clarification. In the book "Inside the Android OS" by G. Blake Meike the author points out, that Bindarized HAL enables Google to deliver updates independently from vendors. But isn't having a stable interface (HAL) and forcing vendors to place vendor-specific implementations into a dedicated image enough already? How "bindarization" is relevant in this context? What am I missing?

Comment: That would probably be the answer - https://groups.google.com/g/android-platform/c/MhzlF4HLIkE.

Comment: That google groups link is a bit old. Basically, Binderization means splitting into RPC, which gives you security boundaries - different processes, different security policies (read - SELinux labels). Just forcing an interface like they did in the < 8.0 HAL wouldn't achieve that since HALs would run in process. Also, stability is now addressed by choosing Stable AIDL over HIDL.

Comment: Well, you basically re-phrased your original answer. I understand why bindarization makes sense in the "security" context. My question was how does it improve "updatability" of the Android framework IF vendor-supplied code already lives in the separate partition AND HAL APIs are stabilized.

Comment: Oh. Then, by that view, it doesn't. Once could argue that sticking to vendor and using interfaces would be enough. Without the Binderization , however, vendors could flout the /vendor partition requirement, and link AOSP code directly. Having everything going over Binder makes the /vendor enforcement by Google stricter.